# Switch from using a class to using a method

Tags: java, encryption, methods

So I've been working on this bit of code for awhile now. It's about encrypting and decrypting a message and producing the two keys used alternatively to encrypt a message using the Caesar Cipher method of changing letters with corresponding letters from a shifted alphabet. For example "Fruit" would be "Hwwnv" according to the shifted alphabets found by implementing +2 to every other letter starting with the first letter, and implementing +5 to every other letter starting with the second letter. I've been using an instance of another class called BreakCaesarThree to find these two keys, `dkey_0` and `dkey_1` and a decrypted message. I would rather use my method breakCaesarTwo instead, because of the ease of having all my necessary code in one class. How would I go about doing this? How do I change it so that I'm using breakCaesarTwo method instead of BreakCaesarThree class, and still be able to print out the `dkey_0` and `dkey_1` and a decrypted message? I am hoping that changing to using the breakCaesarTwo method will yield the right results.

Note: Right now calling BreakCaesarThree doesn't yield a decrypted message or give the right keys (I get 0s).

Here's my TestCaesarCipherTwo code which includes the breakCaesarTwo method:

```
import edu.duke.*;

public class TestCaesarCipherTwo {
     private String alphabetLower;
    private String alphabetUpper;
    private String shiftedAlphabetLower1;
    private String shiftedAlphabetUpper1;
    private String shiftedAlphabetLower2;
    private String shiftedAlphabetUpper2;
    private int mainKey1;
    private int mainKey2;
    private int dkey_0;
    private int dkey_1;

     /**
     * 
     */
    public void simplebreaker()
    {
        FileResource fr = new FileResource();
        String encrypted = fr.asString();
        BreakCaesarThree bct = new BreakCaesarThree();
        String broken = bct.decrypt(encrypted);
        System.out.println("Keys found: " + bct.dkey_0 + ", " + bct.dkey_1 + "\n" + broken);
    }
     public String halfOfString(String message, int start) {
        StringBuilder halfString = new StringBuilder();
        for (int index=start;index < message.length();index += 2) {
            halfString.append(message.charAt(index));
        }
        return halfString.toString();

  }
  public String decrypt(String input) {
      CaesarCipherTwoKeys cctk= new CaesarCipherTwoKeys(26 - mainKey1, 26 - mainKey2); 
      String decrypted = cctk.encrypt(input); 
      return decrypted;

     }
  public int[] countOccurrencesOfLetters(String message) {
        //snippet from lecture
        String alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int[] counts = new int[26];
        for (int k=0; k < message.length(); k++) {
            char ch = Character.toLowerCase(message.charAt(k));
            int dex = alph.indexOf(ch);
            if (dex != -1) {
                counts[dex] += 1;
            }
        }
        return counts;
    }
   public int maxIndex(int[] values) {
        int maxDex = 0;
        for (int k=0; k < values.length; k++) {
            if (values[k] > values[maxDex]) {
                maxDex = k;
            }
        }
        return maxDex;
  }
 public void simpleTests()
    {
        int key1 = 17;
        int key2 = 3;
        FileResource fr = new FileResource();
        String message = fr.asString();
        CaesarCipherTwoKeys cctk = new CaesarCipherTwoKeys(key1, key2);
        String encrypted = cctk.encrypt(message);
        System.out.println(encrypted);

        String decrypted = cctk.decrypt(encrypted);
        System.out.println(decrypted);

        BreakCaesarThree bct = new BreakCaesarThree();
        String broken = bct.decrypt(encrypted);
        System.out.println("Keys found: " + bct.dkey_0 + ", " + bct.dkey_1 + "\n" + broken);    
  }
 public String breakCaesarTwo(String input) {
    String in_0 = halfOfString(input, 0);
    String in_1 = halfOfString(input, 1);
    // Find first key
    // Determine character frequencies in ciphertext
    int[] freqs_0 = countOccurrencesOfLetters(in_0);
    // Get the most common character
    int freqDex_0 = maxIndex(freqs_0);
    // Calculate key such that 'E' would be mapped to the most common ciphertext character
    // since 'E' is expected to be the most common plaintext character
    int dkey_0 = freqDex_0 - 4;
    // Make sure our key is non-negative
    if (dkey_0 < 0) {
        dkey_0 = dkey_0+26;
    }
    // Find second key
    int[] freqs_1 = countOccurrencesOfLetters(in_1);
    int freqDex_1 = maxIndex(freqs_1);
    int dkey_1 = freqDex_1 - 4;
    if (freqDex_1 < 4) {
        dkey_1 = dkey_1+26;
    }
    CaesarCipherTwoKeys cctk = new CaesarCipherTwoKeys(dkey_0, dkey_1);
    return cctk.decrypt(input);
  }
}
```

I'd like to implement the changes here:

```
 public void simplebreaker()
        {
            FileResource fr = new FileResource();
            String encrypted = fr.asString();
            BreakCaesarThree bct = new BreakCaesarThree();
            String broken = bct.decrypt(encrypted);
            System.out.println("Keys found: " + bct.dkey_0 + ", " + bct.dkey_1 + "\n" + broken);
        }
```

and here:

```
 public void simpleTests()
    {
        int key1 = 17;
        int key2 = 3;
        FileResource fr = new FileResource();
        String message = fr.asString();
        CaesarCipherTwoKeys cctk = new CaesarCipherTwoKeys(key1, key2);
        String encrypted = cctk.encrypt(message);
        System.out.println(encrypted);

        String decrypted = cctk.decrypt(encrypted);
        System.out.println(decrypted);

        BreakCaesarThree bct = new BreakCaesarThree();
        String broken = bct.decrypt(encrypted);
        System.out.println("Keys found: " + bct.dkey_0 + ", " + bct.dkey_1 + "\n" + broken);
```

Comment: Instead of `String broken = bct.decrypt(encrypted);` just use `String broken = breakCaesarTwo(encrypted);` - assuming that function does the equivalent of BreakCaesar3's bct(...) method;

Comment: How would we be able to calculate `dkey_0` without `.bct`?